# How to merge gridview rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, merge

I want to merge table but i don't know how. I have already tried many times but still can't get the right solution. Right now my gridview is like this :

```
Data 1  |  Data 1  |  Data 1  |  Data 1
Data 1  |  Data 1  |  Data 1  |  Data 1
Data 2  |  Data 2  |  Data 2  |  Data 2
Data 2  |  Data 2  |  Data 2  |  Data 2
```

And I want the gridview to be like this :

```
Data 1   |   Data 1   |   Data 1  |   Data 1
         |   Data 1   |   Data 1  |
Data 2   |   Data 2   |   Data 2  |   Data 2
         |   Data 2   |   Data 2  |
```

Answer (score 3):

- [How to merge cells with equal values in a GridView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34337/How-to-merge-cells-with-equal-values-in-a-GridView)
  this will help you

The code that merges the cells is very short:

```
public class GridDecorator
{
    public static void MergeRows(GridView gridView)
    {
        for (int rowIndex = gridView.Rows.Count - 2; rowIndex >= 0; rowIndex--)
        {
            GridViewRow row = gridView.Rows[rowIndex];
            GridViewRow previousRow = gridView.Rows[rowIndex + 1];

            for (int i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                if (row.Cells[i].Text == previousRow.Cells[i].Text)
                {
                    row.Cells[i].RowSpan = previousRow.Cells[i].RowSpan < 2 ? 2 : 
                                           previousRow.Cells[i].RowSpan + 1;
                    previousRow.Cells[i].Visible = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The last action is to add an OnPreRender event handler for the GridView:

```
protected void gridView_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridDecorator.MergeRows(gridView);
}
```

Comment: This is a very good example but I already tried this one before and the result is not the same with the example.

Comment: Thank you! I had a similar problem to @20151012 and this did it for me, except that it was for only the first cell. So I took out the for and replaced all references to i to the cell index.